# Can i retrieve DISTINCT value of an array field using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have class object (for simplicity sake, let say, class name is `Person` with fields as FirstName, Lastname, YearBorn)

I get my data from DB but now want to have distinct year(s) in an array, can this be done using LINQ?

I am passing `List<person> Data` as a parameter to a method and want to return an array of `Distinct` year from data.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming YearBorn is a Datetime (?)

```
var years = data
              .Select(m => m.YearBorn.Year).Distinct();
```

if it's an int

```
 var years = data.Select(m => m.YearBorn).Distinct();
```

if it's a nullable DateTime

```
 var years = data
             .Where(m => m.YearBorn.HasValue)
             .Select(m => m.YearBorn.Value.Year).Distinct();
```

Comment: If itsnullable then it doesn't have a year property.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Enumerable.Distinct Method (IEnumerable, IEqualityComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb338049.aspx) where like a second parameter you specify equality rule, so `Distict` will know which entities are considered equal so will skip them in case of more then one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) standard query operator:

```
var years = data.Select(p => p.Year).Distinct().ToArray();
```

If you wish to get all of the people elements that have distinct years, then you can use `DistinctBy` from the [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library.

Comment: Distinct does not accept a lambda as a parameter. You must first `Select` and then `Distinct` the result, as in @Raphael's answer

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but :(

```
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Add(new Person() { Forename = "Onam", Surname = "Chilwan", DOB = new DateTime(1984, 8, 23) });
        persons.Add(new Person() { Forename = "Onam", Surname = "Chilwan", DOB = new DateTime(1972, 8, 23) });
        persons.Add(new Person() { Forename = "Onam", Surname = "Chilwan", DOB = new DateTime(1988, 8, 23) });
        persons.Add(new Person() { Forename = "Onam", Surname = "Chilwan", DOB = new DateTime(1984, 8, 23) });

        int[] years = persons.Select(x => x.DOB.Year).Distinct().ToArray();

    public class Person
    {
        public string Forename;
        public string Surname;
        public DateTime DOB;
    }
```

Comment: And if they're not all born on the same day/month ?